# Get text of option before the currently selected option of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a form where I need to validate a textbox field is between the currently selected dropdown item, and the item immediately before the selected.

Example Dropdown:

```
<select>Select</option>
  <option value="57">25</option>
  <option value="58">28</option>
  <option value="59" selected>30</option>
  <option value="60">32</option>
  <option value="61">33</option>
  <option value="62">35</option>
</select>
```

Given the selected item, 59, I need jquery to give me the value for the previous item, in this case 58. Note this is just an example, the values are not always sequential like this.

I can easily get the item after the selected item in jQuery using:

```
$("#SealShaftSizeID option:selected + option").text();
```

I am unable to find some jQuery to do the reverse of that.

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/prev/.  CSS cannot select previous siblings, but you can still traverse the DOM backwards with `.prev()`

Comment: I'm feeling dumb right now, I searched for this and found nothing. But hey its Friday! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve like this:

```js
$("option[selected]").prev().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
 </select>
```